# Unable to store Json RPC response in react native but able to console.log it

Tags: react-native, parsing, json-rpc, ipfs

We have Json RPC response in {},{},{}

We are unable to save the response as a variable but can see it via console.log()
after doing Jsonrcp.parse(response) which we got from the below library

We are using the JsonRPC-Lite library https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonrpc-lite.

This is our code

```
axios
    .post(
      "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?wrap-with-directory=true",
      data,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
                            this.setState({ apireturm: reponse.data });
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function () {
      console.log("FAILURE!!");
    });
```

Comment: .then(function (response) {
                            this.setState({ apireturm: array });

did you mean 
.then(function (response) {
                            this.setState({ apireturm: response.data });

Comment: Also, please make sure ```this``` is in the context. You might want to try arrow function in promise handlers.

Comment: @Aymen Yes,  it's response.data .. I corrected it.  I am able to console.log it but not able to save it. I think it's mostly a problem of parsing of json-rpc. we tried a lot but it's not working. what do you think?